# Symfony3: Create user without password field, and authenticate programmatically

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I'm trying to create app where users can login by multiple social services, some OAuth some are OpenID, and my User entity doesn't need to have username field or password, but UserInterface requires me to implement getters for username and password (and salt).

What I did is I return user id in getUsername, and null in getPassword and getSalt.

My security is configured to use form_login, but I only provide /login route so unauthenticated users will be redirected to one page where they can find various login options.

I didn't provide route for check_login.

I will authenticate users programmatically with code:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);
```

My question is, is it secure to return null password, and have check_login not set? My goal is to not let users login using form. So they won't login with empty passwords. I have check all I did works so far, but I would like to make sure it won't let users login on other user using empty password.

Comment: I made some tests with returning constant password and providing route for check_login, so I could use that password to login, and it was able to, so I checked what if password returned by user entity will be null, symfony throws exception so authentication won't be possible by login form, and when I removed check_login it just reloads the page, so it seems like I should be good and nobody should be able to login that way.